# Make a private server, public

Tags: vpn

I have a Windows 2003 server which is behind a NAT and I have configured the TFS on it. I want to know that is there any free software or service available that make this server available from the internet using a VPN or something?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I don't have access to the NAT or router settings because My ISP won't allow it.

Comment: Presumably the reason you don't have access to the router settings is that the network admin doesn't want things on the inside exposed to the internet..

Comment: This is the kind of thing an admin should be trying to prevent, not help you with.

Comment: The reason is that my ISP doesn't use public IPs for the users like our company.

Comment: My comment stands. The admins at your ISP certainly wouldn't thank us for helping you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have access to your firewall/NAT configuration, then you don't have any way of making your internal server accessible from the Internet.

Comment: Then how software like LogMeIn can remote desktop?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Massimo, there is no technical way to solve this. The only way to the Internet is through your router.

So this is more a social/political thing. Talk to your admin or possibly your manager about what you need. Then try to find a solution together.

Communication is also an important technical skill :-).

Answer (score 1):

Re "Then how software like LogMeIn can remote desktop?" comment:

It likely uses a server in the middle to handle the connection, so both the client and the server are making outbound connections.  It's a common NAT mitigation strategy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do this:

- Use port forwarding to forward the ports you want to make publicly accessible from your NAT router to your server
- Install RRAS on the server and setup a VPN. This will still require you to forward the ports required for the VPN service
- If your router supports it, place your server in a DMZ (make sure your server is appropriately protected)

However, if you do not have access to the router or network configuration then there's not really a way to do this, and as has been said, it sounds like you shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ooo ok then how about some spagetti like getting a cloud server from Rackspace and somehow bounce the traffic to the internal server via it making an outbound connection like an SSH tunnel to the cloud server. I don't however know what TFS is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you place a second router between your ISPs router and your internal network and set this up to port forward the correct traffic.

If your external IP Address is dynamic then you will have to also play around with something like http://www.dyndns.com/